# I can't get the data from the database in any way. It worked out with one model, I'm suffering with the second one. Python backend, REACT front

Tags: python, reactjs

I have a card with four tabs, on the first tab I get general information, in the second I try to transfer data from the `class SidesCaseInCase(models.Model):` I tried to do everything through postman, but it is not transmitted to the front.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import MyButton from './UI/button/MyButton';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import CardService from '../API/CardService';
import { updateCard } from '../API/CardService';
import CardNavbar from './UI/CardNavbar/CardNavbar';
import CardHeader from './CardHeader';
import CardForm from './CardForm';
import { handleShowDetails, handleAddSide, handleDeleteSide, handleEditSide } from '../pages/Sides';
import SidesForm from '../pages/SidesForm';
import SideService from '../API/SideService';

const BusinessCard = (props) => {
  const router = useNavigate();
  const [side, setSide] = useState([]);
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(0);
  const [isEditingCard, setIsEditingCard] = useState(false);
  const [editedCardData, setEditedCardData] = useState({ ...props.card });
  const [editedSideData, setEditedSideData] = useState({ ...props.side });
  const [showSideForm, setShowSideForm] = useState(false);
  const [isEditingSide, setIsEditingSide] = useState(false);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchSideData = async () => {
      try {
        if (!props.side || !props.side.id) {
          console.error('props.side или props.side.id не определены');
          return;
        }

        const sideId = props.side.id;
        const response = await SideService.getById(sideId);

        if (response.data) {
          setEditedSideData(response.data);
        } else {
          console.error('Данные стороны не получены');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Ошибка при получении данных стороны:', error);
      }
    };

    if (activeTab === 1) {
      fetchSideData();
    }
  }, [activeTab, props.side]);  

  const handleEditToggle = () => {
    setIsEditingCard(!isEditingCard);
  };

  const handleSave = async () => {
    try {
      const sideId = String(editedSideData.id);
      const updatedSide = await SideService.updateSide(sideId, editedSideData);
  
      setEditedSideData(updatedSide);
      setIsEditingSide(false);
  
      handleAddSide(updatedSide, setSide);
  
      console.log('Состояние side после сохранения:', updatedSide);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Ошибка при обновлении стороны:', error);
    }
  };
  
  

  const handleCancel = () => {
    setEditedCardData({ ...props.card });
    setIsEditingCard(false);
  };

  const handleRemove = async () => {
    try {
      if (!props.card.id) {
        console.error('ID карточки не определен');
        return;
      }

      const cardId = String(props.card.id);
      await CardService.remove(cardId);
      console.log('Удаляется карточка с ID:', cardId);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Ошибка удаления:', error);
    }
  };

  const handleTabChange = (tabIndex) => {
    setActiveTab(tabIndex);
  };

  const handleAddSideToState = () => {
    setIsEditingSide(true);
    setShowSideForm(true);
  };

  const createSide = (newSide) => {
    handleAddSide(newSide, setSide);
  };

  const renderButtons = () => {
    if (activeTab === 1) {
      return (
        <>
          <MyButton onClick={handleShowDetails}>Показать детали</MyButton>
          <MyButton onClick={handleAddSideToState}>
            Добавить сторону
          </MyButton>
          <MyButton onClick={handleDeleteSide}>Удалить сторону</MyButton>
          <MyButton onClick={handleEditSide}>Редактировать сторону</MyButton>
        </>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <>
          <MyButton onClick={() => router(`/cards/${props.card.id}`)}>
            Подробнее
          </MyButton>
          <MyButton onClick={handleRemove}>Удалить</MyButton>
          <MyButton onClick={handleEditToggle}>Редактировать</MyButton>
        </>
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="post">
      {showSideForm && isEditingSide ? (
        <SidesForm
          create={createSide}
          editSideData={editedSideData}
          onSave={async (newSide) => {
            const updatedSide = await SideService.updateSide(newSide.id, newSide);
            handleAddSide(updatedSide, setSide);
            setShowSideForm(false);
            setIsEditingSide(false);
          }}
          onCancel={() => {
            setShowSideForm(false);
            setIsEditingSide(false);
          }}
          setSide={setSide}
        />
      ) : null}
      {isEditingCard ? (
        <CardForm
          create={props.create}
          editCardData={editedCardData}
          onSave={handleSave}
          onCancel={handleCancel}
        />
      ) : (
        <>
          <div className="card-header">
            <h5>
              <CardHeader
                align-items="center"
                category={props.card.case_category_title}
              />
              <p></p>
              {` Карточка № ${props.card.original_name}`}
            </h5>
          </div>
          <div className="post__content">
            <div className="tab-content">
              <CardNavbar onTabChange={handleTabChange} />
              {activeTab === 0 && (
                <>
                  <strong>
                    АЙДИ карточки: {props.card.id} Номер карточки {props.card.original_name}.
                  </strong>
                  <div>Автор: {props.card.author}</div>
                  Категория:
                  <div>{props.card.case_category_title}</div>
                  <div>Статья: {props.card.article}</div>
                  Дата создания:
                  <div>{props.card.pub_date}</div>
                </>
              )}

              {activeTab === 1 && editedSideData ? (
                <>
                  <strong>ФИО {editedSideData.name}.</strong>
                  <div>Под стражей: {editedSideData.under_arrest}</div>
                  Стороны по делу:
                  {editedSideData.sides_case ? (
                    editedSideData.sides_case.map((sideCase, index) => (
                      <div key={index}>{sideCase.sides_case}</div>
                    ))
                  ) : (
                    <div>Нет данных по сторонам дела</div>
                  )}
                  <div>Дата направления повестки: {editedSideData.date_sending_agenda}</div>
                </>
              ) : (
                <div>Нет данных для отображения</div>
              )}


              {activeTab === 2 && (
                <div>
                  Третий текст Третий текст Третий текст Третий текст
                </div>
              )}

              {activeTab === 3 && (
                <div>
                  Четвертый текст Четвертый текст Четвертый текст
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr
            style={{
              width: '100%',
              height: '2px',
              backgroundColor: '#d3d3d3',
              margin: '15px 0',
            }}
          />
          <div className="post__btns">{renderButtons()}</div>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default BusinessCard;
```

Sides.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import SideService from '../API/SideService';
import SidesForm from './SidesForm';
import { updateSide } from '../API/SideService';

export const handleShowDetails = (props, router) => {
  router(`/cards/details/${props.side.id}`);
};

export const handleAddSide = (newSide, setGlobalSide) => {
  console.log('Добавляется сторона:', newSide);
  if (newSide && Object.keys(newSide).length > 0) {
    setGlobalSide((prevSide) => [...prevSide, newSide]);
  }
};

export const handleEditSide = (isEditing, setIsEditing) => {
  setIsEditing(!isEditing);
};

export const handleDeleteSide = async (id, setSide) => {
  try {
    if (!id) {
      console.error('ID стороны не определен');
      return;
    }

    const sideId = String(id);
    await SideService.remove(sideId);
    console.log('Удаляется сторона с ID:', sideId);

    setSide((prevSide) => prevSide.filter((item) => String(item.id) !== sideId));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Ошибка удаления:', error);
  }
};

const Sides = (props) => {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
  const [editedSideData, setEditedSideData] = useState({ ...props.sides });
  const [sides, setSide] = useState([]);
  const [showSideForm, setShowSideForm] = useState(false);

  const handleSave = async (editedSideData) => {
    try {
      const sideId = String(props.sides.id);
      const updatedSide = await updateSide(sideId, editedSideData);
  
      setEditedSideData(updatedSide);
      setIsEditing(false);
  
      handleAddSide(updatedSide, setSide);
  
      console.log('Состояние side после сохранения:', updatedSide);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Ошибка при обновлении стороны:', error);
    }
  };
  

  const handleCancel = () => {
    setEditedSideData({ ...props.side });
    setIsEditing(false);
    console.log('Отменено. Состояние side:', props.sides);
  };

  const handleCreateCardClick = () => {
    setShowSideForm(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      {isEditing ? (
        <SidesForm
          create={props.create}
          editSideData={editedSideData}
          onSave={handleSave}
          onCancel={handleCancel}
          setSide={props.setSide}
        />
      ) : null
      }
    </div>
  );
};

export default Sides;
```

SideService.jsx

```
import axios from 'axios';


export const updateSide = async (id, updatedData) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.patch(`http://localhost:8000/business_card/sidescaseincase/${id}/`, updatedData);
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};

export default class SideService {
  static async getSideById(id) {
    const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/business_card/sidescaseincase/`);
    return response;
  }

  static async remove(id) {
    try {
        const response = await axios.delete(`http://localhost:8000/business_card/sidescaseincase/${id}/`, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
            }
        });
        console.log(response);
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        throw new Error(`Ошибка удаления карточки: ${error}`);
    }
}

  static async getById(id) {
    const response = await axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/business_card/sidescaseincase/${id}`);
    return response;
  }

  static async getCommentsBySideId(id) {
    const response = await axios.get(`${id}`);
    return response;
  }
}
```

In this part of the code

```
              {activeTab === 1 && editedSideData ? (
                <>
                  <strong>ФИО {editedSideData.name}.</strong>
                  <div>Под стражей: {editedSideData.under_arrest}</div>
                  Стороны по делу:
                  {editedSideData.sides_case ? (
                    editedSideData.sides_case.map((sideCase, index) => (
                      <div key={index}>{sideCase.sides_case}</div>
                    ))
                  ) : (
                    <div>Нет данных по сторонам дела</div>
                  )}
                  <div>Дата направления повестки: {editedSideData.date_sending_agenda}</div>
                </>
              ) : null}
```

I'm trying to get data from the model, but there's nothing there. I apologize in advance for the crooked code, I'm just learning REACT. Where do I lose my data?

Comment: "I tried to do everything through postman, but it is not transmitted to the front" just to clarify, you are saying that you can see the data from your Python backend when you make a request with postman but not in the browser? Did you check the browser devtools network inspector? Is the request even being made? Do you see the route get hit in the terminal for your backend server when you load the page? It could be that the request never fires, the request fires and the data is there but React doesn't render it etc. etc. Need more details to help you.

Comment: When I go to the address `http://127.0.0.1:8000/business_card/sidescaseincase /` in the browser, it shows me all the data in the form of json

Comment: I tried the option directly `async function fetchSide() {
const response = await axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/business_card/sidescaseincase /`);
console.log('The answer from the sidescaseincase point:', response);
}`
`<MyButton onClick={fetchSide}>
Sides
</MyButton>`
Everything goes through, the console outputs all the necessary data. But in the code itself, the request does not pass somewhere

Comment: You are calling `setEditedSideData` in ~4 different places in the code. It's not clear what request you are making that might be problematic, or what use interactions it's tied to. I strongly recommend stripping this down by commenting out code and have a component that does nothing but have a button that you can click and then a div to render the response data as JSON, the code you have currently is in some need of a refactor. Dial it back to something simple, and build your way back up verifying at each stage that everything works as intended.

Comment: I finally figured it out!) In the `Business Card`, I replaced the code with this `useEffect(() => {
    SideService.getAllSide().then((response) =>  {
      if (Array.isArray(response.data)) {
        setSides(response.data);
      } else {
        console.error('Неверный тип данных в ответе:', response.data);
      }
    });
  }, []);`

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out